# CPU tempterature and fan speed on Dell Optiplex 7080

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

I am running some intense computations on my Dell OptiPlex 7080 at work. All the 12 cores of the CPU are used at 100%, and their temperatures are around 90 degrees Celsius (195 Fahrenheit). They stay stable around that range, and there seems to be very little thermal throttling. However, I am a bit worried that this may be too high (as the computation should run for a couple of days, and I would like to perform similar ones in the future).
Even more so, as I can't here any noise coming from the fan (which may just mean that it's very silent...), and I can't seem to get the fan speed from the `sensors` command.
Finally, I read somewhere that more normal CPU temperatures (at 100% speed) should be around 70 Celsius (160 Fahrenheit).

I would like to know whether it would be possible to:

1. get the fan speed (maybe installing some proprietary driver);
2. regulate the fan speed manually (using `fancontrol` perhaps).

Thank you very much for your help!

**UPDATE**: I should add that I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: There is often a BIOS section, something like PC Health or similar, with fan management options. Another way to mamage CPU temperature is to lower its top frequency, which can be done with `cpufrequtils`.

Comment: The Optiplex line is targeted to professional **office** usages. Dell has other professional lines for the exact purposes you seem to suggest here. That said, Optiplex, Vostro and other entry level machines can most of the times used be for that but they'll be slower. Temps aren't excessive and are within the specifications and shouldn't impact significantly the lifespan of the hardware.

Comment: `sensors-detect` is the command to start with, pay attention to the Super IO section.  Often it will detect a chip but not know what driver to use with it, so keep an eye out for that and post the output if it detects an unknown chip.

Comment: I used to have an optiplex 9010. I tryed and did a lot of searching but could not get lmsensors to do anything with the fans. The pwm files just werent there after running sensors detect. I even tried adding the lax param to kernal line but didnt work. It seems like its a short list of computers that work with fancontrol on linux.